# How can I make skeletons shoot players from far away in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Does anyone know how to make skeletons shoot players from far away using commands? I tried editing their follow range, but all it did was make them look at me from far, but not shoot.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with the commands available at the moment, though it's a very interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

You would like to try the FollowRange attribute for this problem :D

I made a command for you to explain :

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:"generic.followRange",Base:100}],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:bow"},{}]**}**
```

I marked in bold the followRange attribute. This command will summon an skeleton with a range of 100 blocks (and equiped with a bow). You can modify the range maximum to 500 blocks . I tested that so far and it works just fine. Keep in mind that this command is for 1.9 (in 1.8 the attribute still works but don't try the HandItems tag, because it works only in 1.9 and above)

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the 'followRange' statistic works for the skeletons detecting their foes, but applying a 'noGravity' tag would allow their arrows to hit players. Have fun!